# Can you find the actual number of a value in visual c++

Tags: c++, .net, winforms

I'm learning c++ and am curious to see if you can actually see the value you assign to a value.  I've never taken any courses on C++ but i believe these are memory locations.  I'm used to vb.net where you can just do a .tostring to find the value of anything, is there anything similar in visual c++?

Some of these values I"m having difficulty finding are:
0x00001f40
0x000003e8

Is there some website that can 'decode' this into a number or some debugging option in visual studio?  Very new to this language so please be gentle. :)

Comment: Where did you get those hexadecimal numbers from?

Comment: Sorry these are from the debugger

Comment: And what are they the value of?

Comment: You can set the VC debugger to produce either hex or decimal output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use the watch box in visual studio (if I have a lot of variables). The watch box allows you to fill in a variable which will display all of its values (very usefull for objects of classes). These values will display the moment a breakpoint triggers.

An alternative to this is using breakpoints and hovering over the variable in the code when the breakpoint triggers (easiest perhaps for short amounts of code but quite a pain to display everything on big objects).

You might want to make sure hexadecimal display is off (can be found in the toolbar during runtime).